# How do I use Dependency Injection in C# .NET 6 application to pass in different instances of the same object with same interface?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I am creating an Azure Function App in Visual Studio with C# and .NET 6.

I have a service I created (CosmosDBService) that implements the interface ICosmosDBService:

```cs
public class CosmosDbService : ICosmosDbService
{
    private Container? _container = null;

    public CosmosDbService(
        CosmosClient cosmosDbClient,
        string databaseName,
        string containerName)
    {
        _container = cosmosDbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
    }
```

I want to pass two different instances of this service into the Function App.  Each service instance would represent a different container.

How would I set this up in Startup:FunctionsApp class using the FunctionsHostBuilder?

Comment: See [Dependency Injection Unity - Conditional Resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32415954). Although that answer involves Unity, the design doesn't depend on any Unity-specific functionality to work. See Nick's answer for how to register multiple services with the same interface in .NET Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default DI container [does not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement) named such scenarios so you have next options - either create separate interfaces and implementations (and register/resolve them) for each databaseName-containerName pair or create a factory and use it to generate desired `CosmosDbService` instance:

```cs
public interface ICosmosDbServiceFactory
{
    ICosmosDbService Create(string databaseName, string containerName);
}

class CosmosDbServiceFactory : ICosmosDbServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CosmosDbServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public ICosmosDbService Create(string databaseName, string containerName) => new CosmosDbService(
        _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CosmosClient>(),
        databaseName,
        containerName
    );
}
```

Register it with appropriate lifetime and inject it into corresponding class and use it in the constructor to resolve required `ICosmosDbService` instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but I wouldn't recommend it. For instance in your start up if you had the following code:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService, CosmosDbService>();
services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService, OtherCosmosDbService>();
```

both instances would be registered in the Di container. If you had a class that depends on this interface, the following constructor would result in OtherCosmosDbService being injected:

```
public class SomeClass {
   private readonly ICosmosDbService _service;
   public SomeClass(ICosmosDbService service){
      _service = service; // This would be OtherCosmosDbService
   }
}
```

Both would be registered and in this instance, the last one registered "wins". If you wanted to get both then you could change the constructor to this:

```
public SomeClass(IEnumerable<ICosmosDbService> services){
   // Write logic to handle finding which one you want
}
```

Honestly, I would go with Guru Stron's suggestion of creating separate interfaces for each container and registering them separately.

Answer (score 1):

I think your design needs to be more granular - trying to access multiple containers (possibly in multiple COSMOS databases) with one interface/class goes against the SOLID principle of single responsibilty. Think about your domain and work from there 'downwards'

```
public interface ICustomers
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers();
}

public interface IProducts
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts();
}

public class CustomersInCosmosDatabase : ICustomers
{
    private readonly CosmosClient cosmosClient;

    public CustomersInCosmosDatabase(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
    {
        this.cosmosClient = cosmosClient;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("customerDatabaseId", "customerContainerId");

        return container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Customer>();
    }
}

public class ProductsInCosmosDatabase : IProducts
{
    private readonly CosmosClient cosmosClient;

    public ProductsInCosmosDatabase(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
    {
        this.cosmosClient = cosmosClient;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("productDatabaseId", "prodcutContainerId");

        return container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>();
    }
}
```

and your registrations become:

```
    serviceCollection.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
    {
        clientBuilder.AddClient<CosmosClient, CosmosClientOptions>((o) =>
            new CosmosClient("connectionString", new DefaultAzureCredential()));
    });

    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICustomers, CustomersInCosmosDatabase>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IProducts, ProductsInCosmosDatabase>();
```

You are then in the business of injecting Customer collections and Product collections everywhere NOT CosmosDBServices.

Comment: Could you please explain why you use `.AddAzureClients(...)` with `clientBuilder.AddClient<CosmosClient, CosmosClientOptions>` rather than adding `CosmosClient` as a singleton like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880032/1114918?

Comment: Apologies @hansmbakker - I can't believe my answer to the original post was a year ago! For anyone still interested:

MS provide extension methods to cater for the relatively complex/nuanced issues around clients like this. There's nothing stopping you from registering one as you see fit but if you just want the 'off-the-shelf default' this will do it.

Comment: I meant that `serviceCollection.AddAzureClients` comes from the newer SDK generation (namespace starting with `Azure.`). This is available for e.g. the Storage SDK or KeyVault SDK but they seem to have abandoned updating the CosmosDB SDK to that modern generation since 2020 - see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Cosmos/#versions-body-tab and https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/releases/4.0.0-preview3.